# how can check that which uiimageview is presently clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have three `UIImageview`. I set the action for `UIImageview` by using `tapGesture`. I want each UIImageview to have a different action. How can I check that which UIImageview is presently clicked?

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[_imageOne addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[_imageTwo addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[_imageThree addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
}
```

Comment: You can simply add tag value for all the imageViews & while recognising you can get the tag value & can perform appropriate actions.

Comment: yes you can achieve by adding tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect using below code:

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer{
        if (recognizer.view == _imageOne){

        } else if (recognizer.view == _imageTwo) {

        }else
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UIGestureRecognizer` is to be used with a single view. There is this explicit information in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html):

> Gesture Recognizers Are Attached to a View
>
> Every gesture recognizer is associated with one view. By contrast, a
>   view can have multiple gesture recognizers, because a single view
>   might respond to many different gestures. For a gesture recognizer to
>   recognize touches that occur in a particular view, you must attach the
>   gesture recognizer to that view.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly, you can't attach same `UITapGestureRecognizer` to more than one view.**

So, your code will not work and you have to create three `UITapGestureRecognizer` instances and have to attach it to views like below:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapImg1 =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];

[singleTapImg1 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapImg2 =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];

[singleTapImg2 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapImg3 =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapping:)];

[singleTapImg3 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[_imageOne addGestureRecognizer:singleTapImg1];
[_imageTwo addGestureRecognizer:singleTapImg2];
[_imageThree addGestureRecognizer:singleTapImg3];
```

Now, you can use below code to get, which imageview clicked and perform action according to that:

```
-(void)singleTapping:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

   if (recognizer.view == _imageOne){

       //_imageOne tapped

   } 
   else if (recognizer.view == _imageTwo) {

       //_imageTwo tapped

   }else{

       //_imageThree tapped
   }

}
```